# How do I make veterinary syrup to mix with my cat's Metronidazole prescription?

Tags: cats, medicines

My cat was prescribed Metronidazole/Flagyl tablets and they taste horrific.  I know there are compounding pharmacies that use veterinary syrup and would like to find a recipe. The veterinary syrup is only available via prescription but it seems it should be easy to make, or an equivalent.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Have you spoken with your vet or their staff and asked for suggestion on how to administer the medicine? Find out if the pills need to be eaten whole or can be crushed/cut into pieces and put in wet food.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

Crushing a pill and putting it in a home made syrup is a really bad idea.

**Longer answer:**

The digestive tract has different properties along its route. Different medications can have their usefulness significantly impacted by being available for absorption in different areas of the digestive tract.

To get the correct dosage to the patient many pills have a coating over them to ensure that the correct properties exist for them to be absorbed.  When a compounding pharmacy creates a prescription syrup, they don't simply grind up the pill and put it in syrup, they create a complete solution that takes multiple variables into account.

We have more then [20 Questions with answers about giving medications to cats here,](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicines+cats) one is likely to help you keep your cat safe and medicated.

Comment: P.S. Bad idea but a GREAT QUESTION :)